# React Native & Webpack: Confusing when ESLint detects errors

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, eslint

For a React Native project, I'm using `react-native-webpack-server`, `babel`, `eslint` and the `webpack-hotloader`

When `ESLint` detects errors in my Javascript code, the iOS simulator still refresh the app and display the stacktrace. But instead displaying errors reported by `ESLint`, I've of errors from `index.ios.bundle` that can be confusing and hard to debug.

For instance with this code:

```
'use strict';

import React, {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Component
} from 'react-native';

rger // This will cause an error.

export default class ContactsComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is a simple application.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I have this error reported by `ESLint`:

```
11:1   error    "rger" is not defined // Pretty straightforward
```

And this error reported y the simulator (so React Native):

```
Invariant Violation: Application ContactsComponent has not been registered. This is either due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.
```

This error message isn't really straightforward.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to use `ESLint`, maybe by showing the errors directly in the simulator?

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {

  debug: true,

  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: {
    'index.ios': ['./javascript/ios.js'],
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ["babel?stage=0", "eslint"]
    }]
  },

  plugins: [],

};

// Hot loader
if (process.env.HOT) {
  config.devtool = 'eval'; // Speed up incremental builds
  config.entry['index.ios'].unshift('react-native-webpack-server/hot/entry');
  config.entry['index.ios'].unshift('webpack/hot/only-dev-server');
  config.entry['index.ios'].unshift('webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8082');
  config.output.publicPath = 'http://localhost:8082/';
  config.plugins.unshift(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
  config.module.loaders[0].query.plugins.push('react-transform');
  config.module.loaders[0].query.extra = {
    'react-transform': {
      transforms: [{
        transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
        imports: ['react-native'],
        locals: ['module']
      }]
    }
  };
}

// Production config
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin());
  config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
}

module.exports = config;
```

And `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "react/display-name": 1,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 1,
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 1,
    "react/jsx-curly-spacing": 1,
    "react/jsx-indent-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-literals": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
    "react/jsx-quotes": 1,
    "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 1,
    "react/jsx-sort-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "react/no-danger": 1,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
    "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
    "react/no-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
    "react/prop-types": 1,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
    "react/require-extension": 1,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
    "react/sort-comp": 1,
    "react/wrap-multilines": 1,
    "strict": 0
  }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to directly display the error in the simulator. I simply use `eslint-loader` package.